# Trim Date from file name windows script

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do you trim the date from a text file. For example, I have multiple files like:

- test_MX_abc_20091011.txt
- test_MX_pqrdhdsu_20091011.txt
- test_MX_xyieuz_20091011.txt

All files will have test_MX in common but the 3rd part will of different size.

I would like to change into:

- test_MX_abc.txt
- test_MX_pqrdhdsu.txt
- test_MX_xyieuz.txt

I know how to change the file if name is like test_20091011.txt with the below code, But if name has more string along with date, how to do that?

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims=_" %%i in ("%%~na") do (
     move /Y %%~fa %data_in%\%%i%%~xa >nul
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This rename operation can be done for example with:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1-3* delims=_" %%A in ('dir /A-D /B test_MX_*.txt') do (
    ren "%%A_%%B_%%C_%%D" "%%A_%%B_%%C.txt"
)
```

Each file name is separated into 4 strings assigned to loop variables **A** to **D** with using underscore as separator. The loop variable **D** takes everything of file name after third underscore.

Or also working for the 3 files:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /A-D /B test_MX_*.txt') do (
    set "ActFileName=%%~nF"
    set "NewFileName=!ActFileName:~0,-9!"
    ren "%%~F" "!NewFileName!.txt"
)
endlocal
```

This solution assigns the name of a file without file extension and path to environment variable `ActFileName`. Next a new environment variable with name `NewFileName` is defined with name of active file without the last 9 characters (underscore and date string). This modified file name is used next in the rename operation.

Other solutions using commands **for**, **set** and **ren** can be found on Stack Overflow.
Search with the string

```
[batch-file] for set rename files
```

and more than 600 results are presented all using more or less something like above.

For details on the used commands, open a command prompt window, execute one after the other following commands and read output help.

- `dir /?`
- `for /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`

Comment: with your ren command I need to do it once for each file. Below is how I can do, but this will delimit at the first string.
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=_" %%i in ("%%~na") do (
         move /Y %%~fa %data_in%\%%i%%~xa >nul
    )

Comment: Thanks Mofi for your comments. I added more details in my question.